# NotSerializableException on HashMap

Tags: java, serialization, weblogic

I've a hash map like :
`Map gen = HashMap<Integer, MyObj>`

When I execute `AccessController.doPrivileged(gen)`, it throws exception as follows. Can anyone help me on this.

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.HashMap
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)...
```

This code is getting executed in `Weblogic` environment.

Comment: This question makes no sense. AccessController.doPrivileged doesn't take a Map as argument, but a PrivilegedAction or PrivilegedExceptionAction. This code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: oh... yes... I forgot... I've a class which will handle all these and I'm passing the object of this class as parameter to `AccessController.doPrivileged()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key is `Integer` which is `Serializable` by default. What is inside `MyObj`? I mean are there any objects inside `MyObj`?

Comment: Two `String` objects and a `Map` inside `MyObj`

Comment: what is the content of that Map ? If I get it correctly your MyObj is like this MyObj { string, string, Map}. If your Map inside MyObj contains anything which is not serializable then you wont be able to serialize it, try placing transient on your Map (inside MyObj) and see if you still get this exception

Comment: As I said, `MyObj` have 2 `String` objects and a `Map`. That `Map` also have a collection of objects which is already `Serializable`.

Comment: As per your comment, adding transient keyword to the variables which are not needed to serialize, made my code working. Thanks @mprabhat

Answer (score 6):

The objects you store in the `Map` (in your case `MyObj`) should implement the interface `java.io.Serializable`

Comment: I still have same problem after making `MyObj` as serializable. What about the `Key`?

Comment: Make sure that MyObj implements Serializable and you generated a random serialVersionUID property on MyObj.

Comment: I've another `Map` inside `MyObj`. What about this case?

Comment: I'm checking documentation, and I think you are calling AccessController.doPriviliged with a Map param when you should pass a param that implements PrivilegedAction interface.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html

Answer (score 1):

MyObj should implement java.io.Serializable.